# SELECT all when ID is not in another table in one query

Tags: mysql, subquery

Typically with sub queries I usually get additional information on something from other tables. EG getting user details from one table, then in the same query do a sub query and get the users permissions from another. But this time i have found myself stumped, i need to get all the users from table 'primary' which do not exist (with a correlating job_ID) from another table, 'secondary'.

Tables:

```
primary
ID   |   email   |   name
1      a@a.c        a
2      a@b.c        b
3      a@c.c        c


secondary
ID   |  job_ID
1        1234
```

Query

```
SELECT
        ID,
        email
    FROM
        primary
    WHERE
        ID does not exist from this query (SELECT
                                                ID
                                            FROM
                                                secondary
                                            WHERE
                                                ID = `1` AND
                                                job_ID = `1234`)
```

The query should in theory return users with ID 1 and 2.

This would be easy to do with one query then looping the results and running other queries, but is this possible with one mysql query? From other posts on here it seems this is possible when the second match is only on one column and not on multiples like this one.

Comment: "does not exist from this query" = `NOT IN`.  And shouldn't the query return ids 2 and 3?

Comment: @John I deleted my answer because I realized that what I proposed is syntactically correct but does not correspond to what you want. Follow Steve's way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `IN` for example:

```
SELECT id, email FROM primary
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM secondary WHERE id = 1 AND job_id = 1234)
```

That still uses a sub query though, if you wanted to do it without a sub query then using `JOIN` would achieve the same result.  For example, to show all information when it doesn't exist in the other table:

```
SELECT p.id, p.email FROM primary_table p
LEFT JOIN secondary_table s ON s.id = p.id
WHERE s.job_id IS NULL
```

To see this query in action, please visit [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214a2/12/0)

Comment: The second query will not give the same results as the first, on the contrary it will give the opposite results, because you have where conditions on the left joined tabel which is the same as an inner join

Comment: @Gervs you're correct, I made a mistake in my answer which I've now corrected - thank you!

Comment: Almost, but if jobId is in the second table, you'll need to add that filter to the join condition